# createDrawerNavigator and back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

We're using drawer navigator in our app to show the routes in the drawer. Our routes have stacks of pages and users can go into a page. E.g.:

- Home

  - HomeChild1
  - HomeChild2
- About

When user goes to the HomeChild1 or HomeChild2 we want to show back button in the header. We don't want to add a back button in each page's navigation options like below:

```
HomeScreen1.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state } = navigation;
  return {
    title: `Home Screen 1`,
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        name="ios-arrow-back"
        type="ionicon"
        color="#FFF"
        underlayColor="transparent"
        iconStyle={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate.goBack();
        }}
      />
    )
  };
}
```

Is there a way to put this config at the global level - like in the defaultNavigationOptions.

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    hideStatusBar: false,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.baseColor
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.titleColor,
    headerBackImage: ( //this has no affect
      <Icon
        name="ios-arrow-back"
        type="Ionicons"
        style={{ color: "#D8025E", fontSize: 30, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
      />
    ),
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        name="menu"
        size={30}
        style={{ marginStart: 25 }}
        color="#FFF"
        backgroundColor="#FFF"
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
      />
    )
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up using navigation path values.

```js
   defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: () => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "HomeChild1") {
          iconName = "ios-arrow-back";
        } else if (routeName === "HomeChild2") {
          iconName = "ios-arrow-back";
        } 
        ....
        return (
          <Icon
            name={iconName}
            size={30}
            style={{ marginStart: 25 }}
            color="#FFF"
            backgroundColor="#FFF"
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          />
        );
     ...
```